# How to access class and its member in other activity?

Tags: java, android

i made a class User with properties in user.java file and want to access that class in other activity. i made the object of that class in main activity but its not working

```
public class User{

    public static int id;
    public static String name;
    public static String desg;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        User.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        User.name = name;
    }
    public String getDesg() {
        return desg;
    }
    public void setDesg(String desg) {
        User.desg = desg;
    }

}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        User user = new User();
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText desg= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.desg);
        EditText id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);

    ArrayList<user> userlist = new ArrayList<user>();
    Button btn;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Make the class Parcelable and pass it in bundle to next activity

Comment: the `.(dot)` operator is used to access the properties of an object. use it like `user.setId(id);`

Comment: user object is not accessing in arraylist

Comment: i should use the dot operator in main activity to access its properties??

Comment: why getters and setters if public attributes?

Comment: i think you need to go over the basic of java and oop one more time to fully understand whats going on.. just a opinion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanna get edittext's content to the User class object and add this object to arraylist. If so, you can do this part like that.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...

    User user = new User();
    EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText desg= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.desg);
    EditText id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);

    user.setName(name.getText().toString());
    user.setDesg(desg.getText().toString());
    user.setId(Integer.parseInt(id.getText().toString()));

    ArrayList<User> userlist = new ArrayList<User>();
    userlist.add(user);
}
```

And if you send this userlist to another activity, you have to use parcelable. So you can check [Raghunandan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871431/how-to-access-class-and-its-member-in-other-activity#comment65104599_38871431)

Answer (score 4):

Write Capital "U" instead of small "u" like below

```
ArrayList<User> userlist = new ArrayList<User>();
```

and you will be able to access User class in Arraylist

Comment: not sure if it's complete answer, but anyway.. nice catch!

Comment: Thanks @JordiCastilla

Answer (score -1):

Write ('u' is capital here)

```
ArrayList<User>userlist = new ArrayList<User>();
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<user>userlist = new ArrayList<user>();
```

Comment: am i correctly assigning the text values to the members of class user?

Comment: why do you repeat an answer?